# Why does librosa librosa.feature.mfcc() spit out a 2D array?

Tags: python, mfcc

Calling librosa.feature.mfcc() on an audio file spits out a 2D array like so:

```
array([[ -5.229e+02,  -4.944e+02, ...,  -5.229e+02,  -5.229e+02],
   [  7.105e-15,   3.787e+01, ...,  -7.105e-15,  -7.105e-15],
   ...,
   [  1.066e-14,  -7.500e+00, ...,   1.421e-14,   1.421e-14],
   [  3.109e-14,  -5.058e+00, ...,   2.931e-14,   2.931e-14]])
```

My question is what are these? Because I was expecting a 1D array of coefficients, why is it 2D? and what are the dimensions? Maybe this is my misunderstanding of what I should be getting back, however any explanation would be appreciated. I tried looking online but everyone seems to just know what it is.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel-frequency_cepstrum - still didn't help, it still seems like there should be a 1D array...

Comment: I was going to send you [Doc link](https://bmcfee.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.feature.mfcc.html) but now I see the issue - that is **from** the links, just with no explanation of why the values are what they are. That said, their example is time series, over some number of features or whatever, which explains the 2 dimensions. Is your data not time-series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One dimension is the time, the other one are the different frequencies. This link shows how it looks if you plot it:

http://musicinformationretrieval.com/mfcc.html

Answer (score 3):

I got tripped up on this one as well.

Check out https://librosa.org/doc/latest/glossary.html specifically the wording for 'frame'.

You would usually imagine a series of samples going left to right on the x axis - however note that it's referred to as 'y' in librosa.

Let's assume my sample is, with a window of 2 and hop size 1:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

When I expect the following:

```
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 4],
       [4, 5]])
```

What librosa actually gives me is:

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 4, 5]])
```

It seems to be due to convenience for the way librosa likes to display / throw data around.

The simple way to work with what you would usually have in your head is to transpose the *np.array*

```
mfccs = librosa.feature.mfcc(np.array([1,2,3,4,5]))
# The mfccs exists down the columns, not across each row!

array([[-353.18529412],
       [  -9.92147635],
       [   1.39044844],
       [  19.76460942],
       [  25.52789074],
       [ -18.65229483],
       [  17.41164986],
       [  32.40858638],
       [ -13.52776281],
       [   8.38747316],
       [  23.82210792],
       [  16.50381765],
       [ -23.39931177],
       [  40.04480991],
       [   7.76233177],
       [  -2.54971281],
       [   4.81715362],
       [  36.80008536],
       [  -9.8943455 ],
       [  -0.57583487]])

mfccs.T
# Now mffcs[0] (the first row) refers to the first mfcc!

array([[-353.18529412,   -9.92147635,    1.39044844,   19.76460942,
          25.52789074,  -18.65229483,   17.41164986,   32.40858638,
         -13.52776281,    8.38747316,   23.82210792,   16.50381765,
         -23.39931177,   40.04480991,    7.76233177,   -2.54971281,
           4.81715362,   36.80008536,   -9.8943455 ,   -0.57583487]])
```

***For beginners***: what does this do? Think of the matrix (array) being printed on a piece of clear plastic then grab the bottom left and flip the page over moving the bottom left to the top right.

Comment: thanks for this. This tripped me up, too, in the way in did you. Thanks! :)